# Why is Crontab not running my python script?

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am trying to create a cron job that appends texts every minute and my code seems to be working. However, my script does not get run by cron.

I have already tried typing this `env -i /bin/bash --noprofile --norc` in my terminal to simulate the cron executing my cron script which is

```
* * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
```

and it works! However, if i execute it like this

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(tabfile='filename.tab')
job1 = cron.new(command='cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py', comment='CronTest')
job1.minute.every(1)

for item in cron:
    print(item)

cron.write()
```

it does not work.

I am using a mac, if it matters.

Here are my codes:

serverr.py

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(tabfile='filename.tab')
job1 = cron.new(command='cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py', comment='CronTest')
job1.minute.every(1)

for item in cron:
    print(item)

cron.write()
```

pythonChron.py

```
from datetime import datetime

myFile = open('/Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/append.txt', 'a') 
myFile.write('\nAccessed on ' + str(datetime.now()))
```

append.txt

```
Accessed on 2019-07-30 22:56:13.057246
Accessed on 2019-07-30 22:56:29.712203
Accessed on 2019-07-30 23:19:15.792065
Accessed on 2019-07-30 23:22:41.850271
Accessed on 2019-07-30 23:34:51.832505
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:23:24.417114
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:30:30.473127
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:33:37.833229
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:34:27.308541
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:37:39.640581
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:38:17.532211
Accessed on 2019-07-31 00:40:36.648651
```

filename.tab

```
* * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
* * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
*/5 * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
*/2 * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
* * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
* * * * * cd /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest &&  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/alainpierrerayosparonda/Documents/cronTest/pythonCron.py # CronTest
```

My expected result is to append the current time accessed into the appended.txt.

It'd be really great if someone could help me. Also, it is my first time posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I believe it's because you're passing `tabfile='filename.tab'` as an argument to `CronTab()`, which makes it use that file **instead of** the actual system crontab file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, do I replace it with the full path to filename.tab or? If yes, I’ve tried it and it doesn’t work.

Comment: If you want to use your own real crontab file, don't use a filename at all.  Use `cron = CronTab(user=True)`.